# Did anyone receive a Windows update of Broadcom Corporation Bluetooth Controller recently?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, updates

I received a suspicious update (see below) through Windows Update. I asked my friends, but none received that update.

So I wanted to ask if someone else also received this update. Because atm I am worried that Windows Update is infiltrated. Because the description of this update is so generic and the links are so generic as well.

> Broadcom Corporation - Bluetooth Controller - Broadcom Bluetooth
>   2.0+EDR USB Dongle
>
> Installation date: ‎26-‎08-‎2013 09:45
>
> Installation status: Successful
>
> Update type: Optional
>
> Broadcom Corporation Bluetooth Controller software update released in
>   August, 2013
>
> More information:  http://sysdev.microsoft.com/support/default.aspx
>
> Help and Support:  http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub

Comment: What machine do you have, what machine do your friends have, what OS (Windows 7 or Windows 8?). Please try to be as specific as you can.

Comment: I have a Samsung R720, and one other friend as well. Another friend has a Samsung X360 and I think they have the same bluetooth chip. All of us are using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same update on two machines.  One is a old mac book and the other is a mac workstation, both with Win 7.  You can probably verify that the update is legitimate by looking in device manager for a Broadcom Bluetooth device.  In my case, I have "Apple Broadcom Built-in Bluetooth."

If you have  Broadcom device, but you're not sure about the update, you could download the update from Broadcom directly [from here](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php).